# Find the largest value in an unsorted array of integers without using built in Max/Sort function

Tags: c#, arrays, integer, average

Note that all values in the array could be negative.  I can't use a built-in Max or Sort function. For example, find the largest value in a series of numbers such as 42, 80, 93, 62, 71.

What are some different ways I could do this? I have only done averaging using the built in function.

You don't have to complete it, just point me in the correct direction.

```
string res = “”;
int[] arr = { 42, 80, 93, 62, 71 };
for (int k = 0; k < arr.Length; k++)
{
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length – 1; i++)
{
if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
{
int hold = arr[i + 1];
arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
arr[i] = hold;
}
}
res += arr[k].ToString();
arr[k] = arr[k];
}
```

Comment: You could use a loop and a variable `max`. Then compare every value with that `max`-value and overwrite when appropriate.

Comment: Keep a variable with "the highest you've seen so far", starting with the first value (or int.MinValue). Iterate over the numbers, updating the "highest seen" if the next value you see is higher.

Comment: @MethodMan No it is not.

Comment: If you had an unsorted stack of index cards with numbers written on them and needed to find the highest value card, how would you do it?  Start there.  Define that process and codify that logic into your application.

Comment: please show some coded effort this not that difficult respectfully speaking

Comment: use non-built-in [`MaxBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) by @JonSkeet instead :)

Comment: The way I would write this is the same way I do it in my head, you look at 42, realise 80 is bigger so that becomes your newest max number, then 92.. until eventually you realise the answer is 42

Comment: Do it recursively! :) You have a function Max(int array[], int startIndex). The function compares array[startIndex] with Max(array, startIndex + 1) and returns the biggest.

Comment: the answer to your question @Travis is one of 2 things 
`1` do a google search
`2` start by writing code and learning about the basic's such as For Loop, While Loop Do Until, or what we called in the old days `Control Break` coding..

Comment: Add a  2,147,483,647 to the start of the array. there

Comment: @Travis you gonna select an answer to this? or just leave it dead for the rest of eternity?

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive example of code:

```
static int Max(int[] array, int startIndex = 0)
{
    // current value
    int current = array[startIndex];

    // stop condition for recursion
    if (startIndex + 1 == array.Length)
    {
        return current;
    }

    // recursion
    int nexts = Max(array, startIndex + 1);

    // simple comparison
    if (current >= nexts)
    {
        return current;
    }

    return nexts;
}
```

This **isn't**  the solution you should use. Using recursion for this problem is *wrong* (but it shows that there are multiple solutions for the same problem)

Use it like:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 5, 4, 3, 2, 6 };
int max = Max(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at sequence is pair of {first element, tail}. This way it is obvious that max is either first element OR max from the tail. Most languages support some sort of spltting lists/sequences - i.e. C#/.Net gives you `Enumerable` class so:

```
T Max<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)where T: IComparable<T>
{
    var first = list.First();    
    var tail = list.Skip(1);
    {
      if (!tail.Any())
        return first;
    }
    var maxTail = Max(tail);
    return maxTail.CompareTo(first) > 0 ? maxTail : first; 
}
```

Notes:

- don't ever use it in real life as there is non-recursive solution
- as written iterates collection twice (for `.Any()`)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
    int max = int.MinValue;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++){
        if (arr[i] > max){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
```

I tested with the Data `int[]{-1,-2,-152 ,-7,-5,-4,-3,-19};` and the result was -1. I flipped them all to positive and it returned 152.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
     int[] arr = { 42, 80, 93, 62, 71 };
     int maxValue = arr[0];

      foreach(int i in arr){
          if (maxValue < i) maxValue = i;
      }

      Console.WriteLine("Max Value={0}", maxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int max = 0;

    public static int maxAmt(int [] arr, int startIndex = 0)
    {
        int current = arr[startIndex];
        int next = 0;
        if (arr[startIndex] + 1 == arr.Length && current > max)
        {
            max = current;
            return max;
        };

        if (current < max)
        {
            return max;
        };

        if(startIndex < arr.Length -1)

            next = maxAmt(arr, startIndex + 1);

        if (current > next)
            return current;
        else
            return next;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int MaximumNumber(params int[] numbers)
    {
        int max = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if( numbers[i]>numbers[i+1] & numbers[i]>max )
            {
                max = numbers[i];
            }
            else if(numbers[i+1]>max)
            {
                max = numbers[i + 1];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't just dump code as an answer, explain your thoughts so fellow users can understand what's going on. Cheers.